# iPhone & iPad can't playback mp4 videos having no .mp4 file extension

Tags: iphone, ipad, mp4

I am writing the server software that serves mp4 video streams to iphone & ipad via HTTP and in order to make sure video files names that having Chinese characters do not create problems when reading for the devices I have MD5-encoded all the file names which also stripped its .mp4 file extension as well. eg:

2fb92f6e8938c0b94441eeb8d2389649

Now none of the devices are able to playback these video files which used to be fine when having the .mp4 extension. The question is are there any way I can make devices to treat these files as mp4 video streams without specifying the .mp4 file extensions. eg, setting http headers or mime types?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the value `video/mp4` for the `Content-Type` header.